# How to filter by integer in solr keeping 0 in the set as last result?

Tags: sorting, solr

I want to filter my results in solr 6.4.1 by price while still keeping results in the set which have no price and pushing those with no pice to the end of the result list.

dataset example:

```
item1 = $32
item2 = $31
item3 = 
item4 = $33
```

Filter example query:

```
<str>{!tag=price}price:[1 TO *]</str>
```

Result desired:

```
result4 = $31
result4 = $32
result4 = $33
result4 =
```

Using 1 in the filter query will filter the empty result out of the set, pulling 0 as start it will return those items on top of the list.

So the question is in other words is, how to sort by price with 0 as highest price result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field can [be defined with `sortMissingLast`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html#field-type-properties) in `schema.xml` to make documents missing a value be ordered at the end of your dataset.

```
<fieldType name="price" class="solr.IntPointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Be aware that this assumes that the field *is missing*. If it doesn't actually have a value, don't index 0 into the field - don't add the field at all.

Comment: Sounds good. Tried to implement and have removed all values with 0, but the one with the missing price info does not show up if I sort for price, removing sorting will pull it back into the result set.        
<field name="price" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"  />    
<fieldType name="price" class="solr.IntPointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
Solr replaces the 0 search with a *, resulting in: price:[* TO *] in the fq

Comment: You'll have to actually use the field type you've defined in your price field if it's going to have any effect. (i.e. `<field name="price" type="price" ...`

Comment: Right :-) Also upgraded to solr 6.6.5 now to make the type available, reindexed as well, but the result ist still missing. Fieldtype looks ok: Field: price
Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.IntPointField
Flags: Indexed Stored Omit Norms Omit Term Frequencies & Positions Sort Missing Last
Properties √ √ √ √ √
Schema √ √ √ √ √

Comment: If the result _is missing_, it doesn't match your actual query. If you're querying for `[* TO *]`, that means that you're only asking for documents that _have a value_. So if all documents should be included, drop the `fq` (or if it's the main query, use `*:*`).

Comment: If you want the documents to be included, you can't filter them. You can _sort_ them, which is a different operation. `&sort=price asc`. The filter does not sort your documents, it just decides which documents are contained in the result set (i.e. which documents to include).

Comment: Thank you, you where right I had this fq there to fix the issue with the 0 price. Now everything works as desired.